# What is the purpose of a non-parameterized constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Is there any advantage of initializing data members of the class in a Non-Parameterized Constructor? Like, if it takes no parameters, initializing the class data members inside the Non-Parameterized constructor isn't like initializing the values directly in class?
Example:

```
class persons {
 private:
   int age, id;
public:
 persons(){
   age = 2;
   id = 3;
 }
};
```

--> We can do also:

```
class persons {
 private:
   int age = 2, id = 3;
};
```

So, what's the purpose of the default constructor?

Comment: it is not perfectly clear what you mean, probably due to terminology (define -> initialize?). Please provide an example code.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Still not clear what you mean. You cannot declare class member variables inside its constructor, those have to be declared as part of the class. Any variables you declare in constructor are local to the constructor's body. Perhaps a code example would clarify what you mean by declaring members in constructor?

Comment: *"declaring the class data members inside the Non-Parameterized constructor"* would *declare* local variables. Did you mean *initialize*?

Comment: sorry, but the edit did not clarify much (declare is also not the right word). Please show some code instead of describing the code in english

Comment: is it an declared default initialization of member vs. initialization list question? They are equal but they don't have equal rights. You can do only certain things  as inline initialization and it is supported only in newest versions of C++ language in different capabilities. Initialization list existed in C++ anno 1989,

Comment: "Non-Parameterized CONSTRUCTOR" == default constructor

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie not exactly. A default constructor is one that can be called without parameters (ie it can have default arguments), hence "non-parametrized constructor" is a term that is rather useless. I have only seen it in poor tutorials so far

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it's not a bad tutorial, it's a bad translation. That's exactly how those are called in my language if using terms approved by official education system. OP is from Romania, their language is _very_ close to mine as well as approach to professional argot in education. Semantic problems causes me to use english words in my day-to-day work because translated terms are ambiguous and native standard terms are useless.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `(ie it can have default arguments)` You right on point with main problem - they claim here that one with default parameters isn't default ctor (which is self-defined as non-parameterized). Tutor to say that would be slapped, because educational material was approved ~30 years ago and cannot be changed, in result there is some desinformation there.

Answer (score 1):

In old C++ versions, attribute declarations in a class could not contain an initialization. Said differently

```
class persons {
    int age = 3;
}
```

was incorrect and members could only recieve values in constructors.

But there is still a difference between *initialization* and *assignment*. It does not matter for primitive types, but will use different special members for user defined classes.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

// dummy class displaying messages for initializations and assignment
class A {
    int val;

public:
    A(int x = 0) : val(x) {  // initializing constructor
        std::cerr << "Construction from " << x << "\n";
    }
    A& operator =(int x) {  // assignment operator
        val = x;
        std::cerr << "Assignment from " << x << "\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

// 3 classes showing various "initialization" methods
class B {
    A a = 2;     // initialization with an implicit default CTOR
};

class C {
    A a;

public:
    C() : a(3) {};   // initialization
};

class D {
    A a;         // default initialization

public:
    D() {
        a = 4;   // assignment
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is indeed:

```
Construction from 2
Construction from 3
Construction from 0
Assignment from 4
```

The special initializations at the declaration of a members are shared among all constructors (be them implicit or explicit) and are applied before the bodies of the constructors. In any case, the initializations of members are applied in the order of their declarations.